# Android ListView blocks UI

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have the following code for ListView adapter! it works fine but when it is loading the image from server it blocks the UI. I put the BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method in separate thread then it only loads one image for the first object in the listview any ideas?

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return applicationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationPojo getItem(int position) {
        return applicationList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleapp, null);
            holder.appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
            holder.rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateApp);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        try
        {
            final View finalView = view;

            holder.logo = (ImageView) finalView.findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
            logoName = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();

            logoImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(IPClass.SERVERIP + logoName).getContent());

            holder.logo.setImageBitmap(logoImg);
            holder.appName.setText(applicationList.get(position).getName());
            holder.developer.setText(applicationList.get(position).getDeveloper());
            holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(applicationList.get(position).getRate()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Adapter Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView logo;
        TextView appName;
        TextView developer;
        TextView rate;
    }
```

Comment: There are hundreds of SO posts related to just this.  Search aside, a good place to start would be here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Hi, just search for Async Task and then put the line I posted you below inside the AsyncTask...

Comment: I don't see your decodeStream working in a separate thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you handle back-off, scaling, memory, and caching too? I strongly recommend using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)!  `Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.url.com/image.png").into(holder.logo);`

Comment: To day I used the Picasso!!! That works very great! thank you very much. you are the man!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I prefer this solution, when need to load bitmaps in list view:
Once your image is downloaded, add bitmap to cache.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Download image in background and once it's downloaded, show it and add to cache.
On next iteration of "listview getView" at some position, check if bitmap is already in your cache list and load it from there.